# How to add Georeferenced PDF as layer to QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geospatial-pdf

I have some georeferenced pdf's that I would like to open in QGIS. I have read that GDAL version 1.8 and higher will support pdf, and I have GDAL 1.10 installed with QGIS 2.0 on Windows 7, but when I add raster layer then choose my pdf file, I get an error that my file is not a supported source.

Comment: In the OSGEO4W Shell, can you navigate to your Geopdf, run gdalinfo on it, and insert the output in your question?

Comment: gdalinfo gave me     "ERROR 4: 092F088.pdf not recognized as a supported format. GDALINFO failed - unable to open 092F088.pdf"

Comment: the file is not corrupt I can open in adobe reader and also works in Avenza pdf maps app for android.

Comment: If gadlinfo can not open it, it might not be a GeoPDF, but a simple pdf; or only working with Avenza. You have to georeference it manually.

Comment: It is georeferenced I can see my location on the map in Avenza. Is there any other way to tell if its georeferenced? Any suggestion on how to georeference it since I cant open it in qgis.

Comment: I had no issue opening the PDF referenced by @user30184 to QGIS 2.6.1, other than it was VERY slow to load and draw.  It was loaded as a raster layer.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded probably the same pdf from http://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/177864/pdf/092f/092F088.pdf
Then I run gdalinfo with GDAL 1.10 on Windows 7 64-bit. GDAL was installed from gisinternals.com. Gdalinfo finds georeferencing

```
C:\temp>gdalinfo 092F088.pdf
Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF
Files: 092F088.pdf
Size is 6600, 4200
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-123.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
GeoTransform =
  383244.8391245987, 3.386857172932951, -4.931834879719495e-005
  5530149.161139191, -5.662418546658723e-005, -3.386719328594231
Metadata:
  CREATION_DATE=D:20130628154112Z
  CREATOR=ESRI ArcMap 10.0.5.4400
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((383498.6035744368 5516178.8426932972,383498.89611363556 5529895.2499113614,4008
21.16656281275 5529894.7663649889,400821.0596233863 5516178.7470214395,383498.6035744368 5516178.842
6932972))
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  383244.839, 5530149.161) (124d37'34.37"W, 49d54'44.33"N)
Lower Left  (  383244.632, 5515924.940) (124d37'18.95"W, 49d47' 3.94"N)
Upper Right (  405598.096, 5530148.787) (124d18'53.88"W, 49d54'58.53"N)
Lower Right (  405597.889, 5515924.566) (124d18'41.41"W, 49d47'18.08"N)
Center      (  394421.364, 5523036.864) (124d28' 7.17"W, 49d51' 1.59"N)
Band 1 Block=6600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Then I tried to open the pdf with QGIS 2.0.1 and it fails. Conclusion: We both have a QGIS version that does not support pdf. While awaiting such a build that has the support you can convert geospatial pdf files into GeoTIFFs with gdal_translate by using the binaries from gisinternals. The pdf driver in GDAL is exceptional because write support is compiled by default but for read support GDAL must be especially compiled with libpoppler or libpodofo.

Comment: The pdf driver used by QGIS (up to 2.4.0 and the OSGEO4W shell as well) is read/write, but the one from gisinternals is rwvs, probably including vector support: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html

Comment: The "v" in the string means `Supports: Virtual IO - eg. /vsimem` See the full long list of the drivers capabilities with `gdalinfo --format pdf`

Answer (score 1):

The issue should have been fixed for Windows builds with this ticket: http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/408 for OSGEO4W GDAL and the QGIS 2.4.0 and dev versions from the **setup** installer.

gdal_translate works now (it takes some time), even inside QGIS with `Raster -> Conversion -> translate`, but loading the raster directly never ends. This happens in Windows and Ubuntu version.

Maybe the data is too big for QGIS memory.

See also http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8912

Comment: No improvement yet with QGIS 2.6.0. Converting with GDAL to some other format is still the best way to go.