# Convert GeoPDF with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, convert, command-line, geopdf

I'm attempting to convert a USGS US Topo GeoPDF in Windows.  I'm using GDAL 1.11.1.  My initial attempts were with [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/JesseCrocker/5694924), which automates the process by feeding a command to the Windows Command Prompt.  After some initial problems (I couldn't get past line 10), I decided to try directly with the Command Prompt.  I used [this USGS resource](http://nationalmap.gov/ustopo/documents/ustopo2gtif_current.pdf) as a guide, which offers step-by-step instructions for using GDAL in the Command Prompt.  To simplify the process, I have been following the guide literally and using the same Santa Fe topo map.  When I enter the following command:

```
gdalinfo NM_Santa_Fe_20131108_TM_geo.pdf –mdd LAYERS
```

I get this error:

```
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'NM_Santa_Fe_20131108_TM_geo.pdf'
```

I found a few different resources that said that this error could originate from the GeoPDF file format not being compiled into the build, and suggested the following command:

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

When I run this, the GeoPDF format is indeed listed:

```
PDF (rw): Geospatial PDF
```

GDAL functions properly if I read in other formats (PNG, TIF).  Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: Gdalinofo works for me with GDAL 2.0.0-dev from gisinternals.com/sdk.

Comment: Are you sure that the PDF does not contain vector layers? These might not be read by GDAL.

Comment: ogrinfo shows that this PDF contains 12 vector layers. I have not tried to convert them to other formats but at least both gdalinfo and ogrinfo work for me but not for @hfisch. The error message is not very selective. For example wrong filename/path or missing driver are both giving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the geopdf files, I get the same error message with GDAL 1.11.0 that was shipped with QGIS Chugiak, although `gdalinfo --formats` lists the pdf driver as `rw`.

But it works with GDAL 1.11.1 shipped with QGIS Brighton, current OSGeo4W and the binaries from gisinternals.

See also [How to add Georeferenced PDF as layer to QGIS 2.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93705/how-to-add-georeferenced-pdf-as-layer-to-qgis-2-0) for some bug tickets that may have been solved lately, especially http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8912 for handling of USGS Topo pdfs.

By the way, you can now use `ogr2ogr -f sqlite out.sqlite in.pdf` to store the vector layers from the pdf into a sqlite database and display that in QGIS:

[image]

This looks far better in detail than the rasterized output of gdalwarp (and saves lot of disk space too).

Comment: This is interesting.  GDAL 1.11.1 in QGIS Brighton works for me as well.  I downloaded my GDAL as an exe from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.  Obviously something is not working right there.

Comment: This is interesting.  GDAL 1.11.1 in QGIS Brighton works for me as well.  I downloaded my GDAL as an exe from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.  Obviously something is not working right there.

Comment: I have no experience with those sources, so I don't know what is missing there. PDF requires extra libraries for read support.