# Using USGS GeoPDF in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, geopdf

Is there an available patch for importing GeoPDFs, like the topographic maps that are available through USGS, into a session?

Software that costs $3000 is not a viable option.

Comment: Did you see this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53023/adding-pdf-especially-geopdf-to-arcmap-as-data?rq=1

Comment: Possible workaround as noted in  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93705/how-to-add-georeferenced-pdf-as-layer-to-qgis-2-0

Comment: I saw that thread and it didn't seem helpful. Also, an alternative to ArcMap is not really a viable option since I am a consultant and our templates are in Arc and we bill based on the use of the program. Thanks for the tips though! I guess there is no way to import GeoPDFs without an expensive tool.

Answer (score 3):

If using an alternative to ArcMap is an option, QGIS has the ability to add a Geospatial PDF to the map frame.

Depending on how the Geospatial PDF was created (vector-based or raster-based), you will either need to add the PDF using the "Add Vector Layer" button or the "Add Raster Layer" button.  For the sample PDF that I used, I had to load with the raster option.

If ArcMap is required and depending on the number, you could consider opening in QGIS (or use a GDAL command line script) and converting the GeoPDF to a format that Arc can open, like a GeoTiff.

Comment: Just gdalbuildvrt. Then bring in vrt to arcmap